# Want custom cell to update outlet, using data from its delegate

Tags: ios, uitableview, properties, delegates

**Context:**

I'm putting together something slightly convoluted.

I have a selection of custom table cells designed in a single XIB file, each a belonging to `MyCustomCell` class. These cells contain Label outlets, as well as things like steppers and sliders which let the user change the properties that drive the outlets.
Example cell: http://s29.postimg.org/fi15mfn8n/nib.png

These cells are loaded into an `UITableView` elsewhere in my project, which in turn sits in a `UIViewController`. (The reason I am keeping the cell nibs separate from the view they get loaded into is to preserve easy customizability, since this table view needs to contain different cells depending on options the user has previously selected.)

These properties (e.g. the `date` property) are held by the `UIViewController`. When the stepper is tapped, the `UIViewController` updates its `date` property via a delegate system I have implemented.

**Questions:**

My problem is then getting the properties back out of the `UIViewController` and into the Label outlets in the custom cells. How can I do that?

Comment: I've simplified this question, to focus on the bit that's most important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone attempting something similar (multiple views and tableviewcells passing data around), I decided to use a Singleton. It's a separate class instance to host the data, accessible and modifiable by any other class:

DataSingleton.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DataSingleton : NSObject

+(instancetype) sharedInstance;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *dataItem1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *dataItem2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *dataItem3;

@end
```

DataSingleton.m

```
#import "DataSingleton.h"

@implementation DataSingleton


// Singleton boilerplate
+(instancetype) sharedInstance
{
    static DataSingleton *instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return  instance;
}


@end
```

And then any other class can access and modify this single-instance dataset as follows

```
NSDate *date = [DataSingleton sharedInstance].dataItem1
```

Hope this helps anyone else playing around with 'global' data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the steppers and sliders only change the value of the label within the same cell, I'd manage it all within the custom cell class, then update the `UIViewController` with a delegate. Especially if you want to change the value of the label in realtime, this is the easiest method.

I usually then send a delegate call back to the parent `UIViewController` after the slider (or other control) has finished being edited, suck as:

```
- (void) cellDidChangeValue:(int)value;
```

Comment: Hey, sounds like a good solution. Would be cool to understand if there's a way to keep as much code as possible in the VC but if nothing comes through then I will go with this solution. Thanks again

Comment: Ah, looking back, I've just realised that this works for some cells, but not all. For example some cells trigger a segue to another controller, where a value is then set and needs to be reflected in an outlet in the custom cell. Complicated...

Comment: Can I make the custom cell class a delegate for the view controller? Or does that lead to circularity issues?

Comment: It's not best practise, but I think possible. Usually when I want the VC to update a cell, I just reload the table view. And remember the cell will only respond when it's visible.